# Display the arrays i get from classes

Tags: java, arrays

First,I dont want to tell me about abstract class,inherit each.Its just Stereo,Ygro,Aerio classes that starts like public class Stereo{//code inside } there arent ectended any class.With this way i want in my main class named Ekset1 to **call this 3 classes** to get them in **one array**.The array has length i give the length from keyboard A it can be every number but **bigger than 3**, because until 3 it will take  **those slots**  from those classes.If this cant happen with normal classes then please solve it with inherit abstract the main class each.I hope you understand me.In the end when this will done display  the array which has all this 3 classes

```
Food[] pin = new Food[A]; // this the array that include all classes Stereo, Ygro, Aerio
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
    pin[i] = new Stereo(); //this is a class start i=0 
    pin[i + 1] = new Ygro(); // this is a class
    pin[i + 2] = new Aerio(); // this is a class
}
```

Comment: Not sure what your question is. Can you demonstrate what you are saying through more code?

Comment: Are `Stereo`, `Ygro` and `Aerio` subtypes of `Food`?

Comment: yes there are subtypes

Comment: if there wasnt subtypes could it be used by that way?

Comment: Java is strongly typed. You can only have a single type of object in an array.

Comment: I would edit my post for better understanding the readers.Your answer doesnt think is right

Comment: someone now understand it?

Comment: If they are not subtypes then you cannot put them in the same array. You wrote that they are not extended from any class. If they are not extended from Food then they are not a type (subtype) of food and cannot be stored in the array.

Comment: thanks a lot  :) i didnt know this sorry for asking but i didnt find nowhere this.Can "main" Ekse1 be the abstract class? no ? Anyway,do it with subtype just to learn and i how can i do it please .Thanks a lot again :D

Answer (score 1):

EDITED:

```
Food[] pin = new Food[A];
```

This is an array of type Food. It can hold objects of type food and other types of food (pizza, corn, potato), which are extended from Food. If you did not extend your Stereo class from Food, for example, then you cannot store any instances of it in this array.

Look at this tutorial, or find another one on generic inheritance, to help you understand this concept.

http://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2014/03/generics-and-inheritance.html

Comment: static int A;  is given by keyboard.

Comment: it doesnt seem that in the first 3 slots of the array it takes the classes.I think is wrong.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a link that should help you understand about generic inheritance.

Comment: i know how it works inheritance.I dont know how to use the 3 slots man.The first 3 slots should be the classes and after them  i dont know maybe  something like this pin[N-3] = Userinput.getInterger();

Comment: You also cannot store an integer in an array of type Food. It doesn't seem like you understand inheritance. I suggest you learn about it before continuing. Have a nice day.

Comment: so int[] pin=new int[A]; if i understand good? i have this code from another and it was using this and it was right.Now how it can be wrong i dont know.

Comment: If you want to store only integers in the array then this will create an integer array of length A.